# Bones and Mesh misaligning when rotated

Tags: bones, weight-painting, parent, vertex-groups, pose-mode

I'm relatively new to making posable models, and I'm experiencing an issue where some bones near the head bone and meshes near the head mesh are misaligning when the head bone is rotated. I've tried Weight Painting the meshes so they all move in tandem with the head bone, but this doesn't seem to fully fix my problem. I also tried parenting some of the bones to the head bone, but that seems to have misaligned them further. Any help at all here would be appreciated!

[Blend file here](https://www.dropbox.com/e/scl/fi/fjc5t51xjrohyrpj5yyvd/Pieroggi-w-Skeleton-Mesh-Bone-Fixes.blend?dl=0&rlkey=jwjpknvqfjwkly6xiuabneluj).

[image: Before Rotation]
[image: After Rotation]
Here are the meshes I weight painted to move with the head's vertex group
[image: Bobbles Mesh]
[image: Back Hood Mesh]
[image: Tongue Mesh]
Here are the bones I tried parenting, and what happened when I rotated the head
[image: Bones Parented]
[image: Bones Misaligned]

Comment: Almost forgot! Here is the Blend file: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fjc5t51xjrohyrpj5yyvd/Pieroggi-w-Skeleton-Mesh-Bone-Fixes.blend?rlkey=jwjpknvqfjwkly6xiuabneluj&dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John points out, first apply the scale of your objects, and check the normals and recalculate (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) when they are inverted:

[image]

Your problem is that the vertices of these parts are part of vertex groups that they should not part of, therefore they are influenced by other bones, see if I select a vertex of this part and check in the *N* panel:

[image]

To fix that, select all the vertices and remove from all groups:

[image]

Now you need to parent the first bone of each hat chain bone to the head bone (with the *Keep Offset* mode). If you want these hat bones to control the hat object, select the armature, shift select the hat, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select the bone chain with <kbd>LMB</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>, and go into *Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones:*

[image]

At the end, maybe it would make it easier to join all the objects into one object, unless you have a good reason not to?

Comment: Also all the objects and the armature need the scale applied and two parts of the object ("nose" and back of hat) have inverted normals!

Comment: @John Eason Oh OK I didn't check everything

Comment: Those are usually the first things I check with animation problems because they're quick and easy. Then I go on to vertex weights, etc. :^)

Comment: @moonboots Wouldn't removing the vertex groups also prevent the hat, hat bobbles, and tongue (the part that may have been confused for a nose) from being affected by their respective bones? I'd like those to be posable as well if possible.

Comment: Oh yes of course, I didn't realize that, please see my edited answer and tell me if it answers?

Comment: @moonboots I followed all of your directions, but the head's bones and some of the meshes are still misaligning. Also, not all meshes are joined because I want them to be moved independently and not pulling on the meshes their joined to, or so it would be easier to fix any remaining weight errors. That said, I did join the all of the head an hat parts together, but the bobbles are still detaching when the head bone is rotated. (link [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/magrh7u3l82adgnaz4lze/Pieroggi-w-Skeleton-Mesh-Bone-Fixes-8-15.blend?rlkey=z51rpnyag89c1w9fcpgutfy5v&dl=0), file marked 8-15)

Comment: Separate each part as a separate object as it was before (you'll join them afterwards if you want), for example the bobble, in Edit mode select all the vertices and Delete All Groups, then select the Armature in Object mode, Shift select the bobble, switch to Weight Paint mode, select all the bones and Weights > Assign Automatic From Bones